# Find the list from list of lists whose avg is closest to a given number in python?

Tags: python

Given `l = [ [3,4,5], [30,40,50], [300,400,500] ]` and a number 45

`foo(l, 45)` should return [30,40,50] since it's avg is closest to 45.

What's a good way to write such a function "foo"?

**EDIT :**

Here's my code.. (not tested yet)

```
def _avg(l):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l)/len(l)

def foo(clusters, point):

    return min(clusters, key=lambda x: abs( _avg(x) - point) )
```

Comment: You do realize you need to show what you yourself have tried?!

Comment: @Ashish: is that the reason of -4 vote you think? cause I didn't expect that.

Comment: Yes (mostly), good that you have edited now. Removing my downvote :)

Comment: Two comments: 1) you want to divide by `float(len(l))` to avoid running into issues with integer division (try `foo([ [30,40,50], [31,40,50] ], 45)` to see what I mean); 2) use `sum` instead of `reduce`. Here is a one-liner version of your solution `def foo(clusters, point): return min(clusters, key=lambda li: abs(sum(li) / float(len(li)) - point))`

Answer (score 1):

Find the `min` of a generator expression that generates `abs(sublist_average - target_average)` values.

```
l = [[3,4,5],[30,40,50],[300,400,500]]
avg = 45
result = min(((i,abs(sum(x)/len(x)-avg)) for i,x in enumerate(l)),key=lambda x:x[1])
#result = (1, 5.0)

print('the minimum delta, found at index {}, is {}'.format(*result))
#the minimum delta, found at index 1, is 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you do this on paper? You'd start by computing the average of the first one, take the difference, and save off the index of the smallest distance so far. The simplest solution, is probably the best, most understandable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Written very verbosely...

```
import sys
def closest_average_to_num (list_of_lists, num):
    closest_list = []
    lowest_diff = sys.maxint
    for list_of_interest in list_of_lists:
        avg = sum(list_of_interest) / float(len(list_of_interest))
        if (lowest_diff > abs(avg - num)):
             lowest_diff = abs(avg - num)
             closest_list = list_of_interest
    return closest_list
```

Example Output:

> ```
> >>> closest_average_to_num ([ [3,4,5], [30,40,50], [300,400,500] ], 45)
> [30, 40, 50]
> ```

Comment: Okayish attempt @davecom, but you should've just stated pseudo code instead of writing actual python code if you don't want to test the code.